# How do i download google spreadsheet using python?

Tags: python-2.7, google-drive-api, google-cloud-platform

Please suggest if anyone knows how can we download spreadsheet using python.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here you havethe official documentation from google. Read it, try to implement what you ask (or use third-party packages) and if you still have problems, ask again. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This component is useful for downloading spreadsheet using sheets API in python. Please refer to the link below to understand the end to end process.

https://github.com/Countants-Team/download-google-spreadsheet-using-python

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed instructions on setting up the credentials and on how to use it!